# TYPO3 tt_news & realurl

Tags: typo3, tt-news, realurl

Could someone help me with configuration of realurl and tt_news?
Now URL of my article is:
**news/tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=2&cHash=4b99bd1be238096e329a50f38cf34b57**

But I want something like this:
**news/title-of-my-article**.

I am using latest Typo3 (ver. 6.0)

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

There is sample RealURL configuration in tt_news' folder, just copy its elements tou your own realurl manual config: `typo3conf/ext/tt_news/res/realUrl_example_setup.txt`

Most interesting for you are `postVarSets` and probably `fileName`.

**Edit**

To get rid some parts you need to use `fixedPostVars` as described on known posts of Dmitry Dulepov (*it's worthy to read it at all, he's RealURL's creator*):

1. [RealURL made easy 1](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/05/realurl-made-easy-part-1.html)
2. [RealURL made easy 2](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/06/realurl-made-easy-part-2.html)

Comment: My URL is now: news/article/title-of-article/. Is it possible to remove word "article" from URL? So that URL would be only news/title-of-article.... Thanks